# Drill down based on parent-child relationship

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to drill down based on parent-child relationship in AWS QuickSight? For example revenue of restaurants where the restaurants are in group hierarchy and we want to show the sum of revenue on specific level of hierarchy. The group levels are dynamic and based on parent-child structure.

Here is how we render the groups in web app:

[image]

Group data is in table with columns group_id, group_name, group_parent_id.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this when you create the visual by adding a drill-down layer in the field well. See the link here - https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-quicksight-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/adding-drill-downs.md

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link but it describes how to add a fixed hierarchy, when all levels are refined by design of table. I need to implement a hierarchy based on parent-child relationship.

Comment: Could you maybe share an example of what you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is using actions and parameters. By passing the field that establishes the join between the parent and the child, using a parameter, you could achieve that drill down. It is a more elegant method than the previous URL only approach. It is explained quite well in this workshop : [AWS Quicksight - Adding Interactivity](https://learnquicksight.workshop.aws/en/author-workshop/3.add-interactivity.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I was reading it but I do not see the possibility to drill down in parent-child relationship...

Comment: It is more visual trickery rather than actually drilling down, like how Power BI does it, but it should deliver the outcome your want?